# Google PageSpeed tells me invisible Google reCAPTCHA v3 CSS is too slow

Tags: recaptcha, pagespeed, invisible-recaptcha

I have hidden reCAPTCHA v3 badge using the recommended approach of CSS display none.

But the problem is Google PageSpeed tells I am have 90kb of CSS file that isn't being used and I get a penalty. I had a good PageSpeed before after a lot of work, but since adding reCAPTCHA my score has reduced significantly.

Is there a way to fully avoid loading the CSS file (and associated Roboto fonts) that are also included.